# Performing while loops using a button in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, while-loop

I need track data of app usage using tkinter.
the code of the loop is....
'''while True:
current_app = get_active_window()
if 'Google Chrome' in current_app:
current_app = url_to_name(get_chrome_url())
timestamp[current_app] = int(time.time())
time.sleep(1)
if current_app not in process_time.keys():
process_time[current_app] = 0
process_time[current_app] = process_time[current_app] + int(time.time()) - timestamp[current_app]
print(process_time)'''

I need to perform this code using a button,
but when i start the window doesn't respond me.
**is there any method for performing while loop along with tkinter window?**

Answer (score 0):

That comes from the `mainloop()` function that is in the `Tkinter`. You can not insert a `while loop` to the `Tkinter` program, because it will freeze it. If the freeze is not a problem for you, then you can do such a thing, but that is not recommended.

Comment: But, i need to use it further also, I mean further features of the app could be used.

Comment: so it will be frozen. There is no way to avoid that.